# Can I interact with a creature exiled with Eldrazi Displacer?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

So I've been playing an Abzan displacer deck for some time now and the following interaction only just occurred to me:

I have an [Eldrazi Displacer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eldrazi%20Displacer) and a [Wasteland Strangler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wasteland%20Strangler) in play and my opponant has two creatures.

Can I target one of his creatures, and then in response to it entering the battlefield being on top of the stack (whilst it's still in exile) flicker my wasteland strangler and put that creature into the graveyard from exile instead of back on the battlefield and obviously give another creature -3/-3?

I think the crux of the question is: is the creature targeted by eldrazi displacer intractable whilst in exile?

Comment: OTOH, Wasteland Strangler's ability could move a card exiled with [Otherworldly Journey](http://magiccards.info/ddadvd/en/16.html) or [Journey to Nowhere](http://magiccards.info/cmd/en/17.html) into its owner's graveyard. If it did, the card wouldn't return the battlefield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically, the effect of Displacer, while the ability itself uses the stack, the creature actually blinked is not on the stack.  When the ability resolves, the entirety of the ability happens, before priority is regained.

Answer (score 6):

Specifically for Eldrazi Displacer, no. Its ability's effects all resolve at once, so the creature will be exiled and be put back onto the battlefield immediately. Unlike say, Flickerwisp, there is no delay in returning the creature, so there is no chance for you to target it in exile.